# How to handle escape and return key in an onCommand handler>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I am using an On_Command handler, and want to specifically use the return and escape keys for different functionalities. Please help me to understand how to do it as i am kinda struck. Thanks.
This is what i have done so far `ON_COMMAND(IDC_CALC, &CALC::OnGlobalCALC)`

and the handler is

```
void CALC::OnGlobalCALC()
{
   //Please suggest what to code here
};
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you want to read user input (keyboard) within the command handler?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard input is usually sent via WM_KEYDOWN (OnKeyDown) messages. So you can handle them there if you have a CView or CFrameWnd.

But this messages are only sent to the window that has the focus.

If Enter and Escape have a global functionality in an application you can assign and use an accelerator table. In this case you can define that enter or escape are handled by the accelerator (usually in PreTranslateMessage) and are converted into a WM_COMMAND message.

But what you want and need to use is heavily dependent on what you really want and what kind of windows you have.

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN` is the wrong message to handle. You'd have to implement a fairly non-trivial state machine to identify the key combinations you are interested in. Using accelerators is really a lot easier, and doesn't require any code (certainly not in `PreTranslateMessage`). You are correct, though, the question is **way** too vague to make any sort of educated recommendation.